VCOV package unable to create a confidence interval
I am attempting to finish an assignment for my linear regression class. Currently, I am looking at a least absolute deviations model and attempting to compare against a Ordinary Least Squares model. The question wants us to provide the confidence intervals and point estimates. Currently, I've been able to complete all other parts but I am receiving an error message when I calculate the LAD interval. Here is my code.
library(quantreg)

LADmodel <- rq(model)
summary(LADmodel)
olsmodel <- lm(model)
summary(olsmodel)

# Get coefficients and their 95% confidence intervals for LAD model
cof <- coef(LADmodel)
ci <- confint(LADmodel) #This the only line that doesnt work

olscoef <- coef(olsmodel)
olsci <- confint(olsmodel)

Upon running that one line, this the return message in my r console.

Error in UseMethod("vcov") :    no applicable method for 'vcov'
applied to an object of class "rq"

I tried find help online but did not find anything good. If anyone knows why this is and/or any great resources I could use to get around this it would be heavily appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106310/calculating-95-confidence-intervals-in-quantile-regression-in-r-using-rq-functi

Hi there, thank you for this. While this does help me, would you be able to break it down a little more for me to understand? Do I just need to bootsrap the LAD, cbind it all, filling in appropriate x and y variables, plot the two original variables and then abline OLS and LAD? I apologize if it seems like I am trying to get a direct answer from you, I am just trying to make sure I am understanding the concept correctly.

From your question, you seem to just want the CI's for the coefficients, thus don't need the plotting stuff. The linked answer suggests t(apply(boot.rq$B, 2, quantile, c(0.025,0.975))) for percentile CI's. -- for your x and y's in the boot.rq call.  Also, a good suggestion is to use the boot package to calculate the CI's using different methods from percentile as an alternative
